# How make an hover effect on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want add a hover effect on my entire div (not image), ([like this example](http://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/ZYNOBZ)) but doesn't works, I need keep this form of html, because has others properties.
I need your help please.. thanks.

```html
   /** DIV WITH EFFECT */ 
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-3 main-sidebaramberse sidebaramberse siverge">
   <ul id="main-sidebarambersese" class="siverge">
  <li id="armonioso-text-2" class="widget widget_armonioso_text">
     <div class="armonioso- textwidget-wrapper  armonioso-textwidget-no-paddings">
        <div class="armonioso-textwidget" data-style="background-image: url(www.myweb.com/myimage.jpg);padding: 40px 30px ;color: 
           #ffffff;text-align: center;">
           <h5>ONE TOPIC</h5>
           <h3>SECOND</h3>
           <p>Something to say...
           <p><a class="btn alt" href="/authors.html" 
              target="_self">Authors</a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </li>
   </ul>
</div>
/** DIV WITH EFFECT */
```

Comment: First off, remove the `/* */` out of your html, to line comment in HTML use `<!-- -->`

Comment: In CSS, for your current HTML, can't you just use `div.siverge:hover{ /* effects */ };`, or one of the other classes assigned to that div instead of siverge? Are you looking for a specific effect that's not working?

Comment: @mark.hch thanks you!! this works, now I have one problem more... how can I do for put an exception for the effect, I don't want apply the effect for the letters and the button... how can I do?, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put an id on div and use the next selector on your css file:

```
#div's_id:hover{

    /*effects u wish*/
}
```

If u cannot see the effect, probably, is because the other elements are above.

Comment: Hello!, thanks you!! this works, now I have one problem more... how can I do for put an exception for the effect, I don't want apply the effect for the letters and the button... how can I do?, thanks

Comment: I need more inf, what css rules are you using?

Comment: This is, but I don't want apply the effect to all, only to the image... how can I do?... `.armonioso-textwidget {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
 filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.armonioso-textwidget:hover {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
 filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
} `

Comment: You must to set explicitly the desired properties which that code modifies, on this div direct children.

Comment: can you explain me a little more of this? please... or maybe some helpful article?... thanks @xpeiro

Comment: If you would set on parent div color: red; (red text), all elements inside of this would take this attribute (red text). How could I fix it? Setting on the immediatly element color:black; (if earlier was black or I desire black).

This means you must to go one by one setting it? - No. Just on the immediatly, and in your case I recommend you to create an extra div which encapsulate all the content of the siverge's div and set again the earlier attributes just in it. You got it? 

Check inheritance, w3schools preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a specific effect?

If not and all you are trying to achieve is hover effects on the given div just use the class `siverge` you have?

Apply hover effects in your css file like this :

```
div.siverge:hover {

 /*styles to be applied on hover*/

};
```

Comment: Hello!, thanks you!! this works, now I have one problem more... how can I do for put an exception for the effect, I don't want apply the effect for the letters and the button... how can I do?, thanks